# moving object across screen smoothly in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm programming a game in as3 using flashDevelop
the player (among other things) is moving across the screen 
using EnterFrame event which update his coordinates 
while he moves its hard to see details of the animation and its look kinda blur 
how do i fix this problem?

Comment: you may want to set the pixel coordinates to integers.

Comment: Another thing that might be useful depending on the type of movement and animations you want is Tweens. Just google "Flash as3 Tweens" or check out a simple tutorial like [this](http://www.zedia.net/actionscript-3-tweens-tutorial/)

Comment: What is the object that you are animating? A vector or bitmap?

Comment: i'm pretty sure its a vector. (its not a bitmap)

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick mentioned you should avoid non integer co-ordinates. You just need to round the values. So instead of:

```
clip.x += value
```

Use:

```
clip.x += Math.round(value)
```

If you set non-integer co-ordinates Flash the clip may appear blurry due to anti-aliasing as Flash is trying to split pixels. You could also try increasing the frame rate.

Comment: i have one that this way clip.x+=int(value), i guess it is the same but i cant see a different

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Tweening libraries?

Some of them are lightweight and automatically make calculations on the movement according to the FPS ( which you should try to maintain high )

Here are couple of them:

1. http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/
2. http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

Hope it helps

Comment: i prefer to do it myself maybe u can explain how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

may this can be helpfull for you. 
[Optimizing transition/movement smoothness for a 2D flash game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284886/optimizing-transition-movement-smoothness-for-a-2d-flash-game)
There is 2 ways to optimizzation.

Answer (score 0):

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, smothMove);

var i:int = 0;
var j:int= 1;

function smothMove (event:Event):void
{

clip.x = clip.x + i;
        i = i + j;

}
```